# XSP2: My mac is inaccessible on port 8080

Tags: macos, networking

I'm trying to provide a mono web service to someone at my house on the local network, but they can't seem to connect on my IP address at port 8080. I can get there via 127.0.0.1:8080, but he can't via my 192.168 address. What can I do to start troubleshooting this? I've never really investigated a network problem on my Mac before. Sorry if this is a noob question, feel free to direct me to a web resource if it applies.

Comment: I'm assuming you're running Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard (non-Server), correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running it from the command line? Try explicitly spelling out the ip when you run the server:

```
xsp2 --address 192.168.1.100
```

Or whatever your actual IP is. You could also use the `--port` flag as well if you wanted to use port 80 or something.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you can locally reach the port and I presume the other person can ping your "`192.168`" IP address, I'd expect a firewall related problem on the path.

You can probably use the [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/cocoapacketanalyzer.html) to check if their connection attempts are reaching your server.

When `ping` is confirmed to work, the next step is usually to try a "`telnet your_ip 8080`" from the client side machine to check they can reach the server (no firewall is filtering communication).

From the client side, if `telnet` connects successfully (don't expect any other activity on telnet with your port 8080) then port 8080 is reachable.

From the server, using a packet analyzer, if you see TCP-SYN packets from the client machine, again connectivity is confirmed. You can probably even use `netstat` to check recent connections after a `telnet` attempt.

If all these checks fail to show connectivity, you need to check,

1. firewall configuration for incoming connections at the server machine

   - firewall settings on any network devices within your home network
   - firewall settings on the client machine (this is very unlikely to be a problem)

Answer (score 0):

its a firewall problem for sure. I'm not a mac person, but Try to disable your firewall
also try having the other person go to yourip:80 doubt it, but it might work